# Nested array in URL params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I would like to make the following work:

```
http://localhost:3000/reviews/new?ticket[]=token[]=109u11
```

It can be thought of as meaning `params[:ticket][:token] = 109u11`

Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need change url like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/reviews/new?ticket[token]=109u11
```